# Work Out Height Based on Width and Ratio

Tags: geometry, ratio, rectangles

I'm trying to work out the height of an image. I have this data available to me:

```
width: 320
ratio: 0.66
```

Is it possible to work out the height based off the data above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know whether the image is in portrait or landscape mode, yes.  If it is in portrait, the height is greater than the width and you have $\frac {320}h=0.66$  If in landscape, the height is less than the width and you have $\frac h{320}=0.66$  Note that $0.66$ may be incorrectly rounded from $\frac 23$ and you may prefer to use that.